# Why do some strings look the same but are deemed non-identical when checked for string equivalence?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

I'm currently trying to tackle a question from my assignment which asks why similar looking strings are checked to be non-identical.

The question is stated as below:

In a computer program’s code,  two string variables are declared. When their respective values are printed by the program onto the computer screen, both appear as the string "ĝ" . However, the program returns false when  both  variables  are  checked  for  their  string  equivalence  (i.e. false means  both  strings are considered non-identical).

What  could  be  the  most likely cause of  these seemingly contradictory  results? Assume that the UTF-8 encoding is used by the computer program.

The question expects to give a reason on why such contradictory result occurred and how the UTF-8 encoding works in this scenario

My current bet is that there is another character that looks similar to "ĝ" but has a different unicode representation but I'm not entirely sure about it as well.

Comment: That's about unicode basics, the specific format is immaterial. Check invisible characters, normal forms (precomposed vs. decomposed), and the exact comparison rules used.

Comment: Analysis via the character encoding seems irrelevant. Perhaps it is just to indicate that the character set is Unicode.

Comment: In addition, there are various characters that just look the same. K, Κ, К,  and K spring to mind. This is always something to be aware of.

Comment: To expand on MrLister's comment, that would be Unicode codepoints `U+004B LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K`, `U+039A GREEK CAPITAL LETTER KAPPA`, `U+041A CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER KA`, and `U+212A KELVIN SIGN`, respectively.

Comment: Unicode provides a list of and [explorer](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp) for "confusables."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode has *combining characters*, so you could have:

```
U+011D LATIN SMALL LETTER G WITH CIRCUMFLEX
```

or:

```
U+0067 LATIN SMALL LETTER G
U+0302 COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
```

Visually these will print the same (Python code example):

```
>>> print('\u011d \u0067\u0302')
ĝ ĝ
```

FYI, in UTF-8 encoding, that would be hexadecimal bytes `C4 9D` vs. `67 CC 82`.

Comment: And as such, you need to *normalize* your strings before you then compare them.